# xmpp server with xep-0065 bidirectional bytestream

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, openfire

According to [xep-0065](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0065.html) bytestream can be bidirectional. I have tested openfire and ejabberd and it looks like its contains only unidirectional bytestream service.

So the question is: is there some xmpp server with bidirectional bytestream (or it is possible to setup it on openfire/ejabberd) or maybe some external proxy65 server?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the poxy server at https://github.com/mmatuska/proxy65 this often works